# Low cost PWM sweep

Tags: pwm, 555

I have this project where I need to try and get a PWM duty sweep starting at around 30% up to 100%. The issue I have is that we don't have anything left in the design (BOM Cost). I would normally use a PIC but there are a few issues, firstly I need an operating voltage range of preferably 2-15V (with a PIC would also need a LDO).

I've been looking at 555 timers, the ones with the voltage range I need are a bit more expensive but can create the PWM, but anyone know how I can create the sweep from 30% to 100%? this can be done anywhere between 500ms to 1s if needed.

Thanks

Comment: You can make a [PWM generator](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-ab&biw=1366&bih=654&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=Xe4TW-nHOsHz9QP3v7zICg&q=555+pwm+generator&oq=555+pwm+&gs_l=img.1.9.0l2j0i67k1l3j0l5.63042.63042.0.65594.1.1.0.0.0.0.130.130.0j1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.img..0.1.130....0.zSo8Qm1mNds) with 555 but you can only sweep manually.

Comment: There could well be an option to do something with all the other components in your project that you haven't told us about. Why not? Put all the relevant information into your question along with the power supply constraints and PWM frequency.

Comment: You have to specify **how** you want to be able to change the DuCy. If only manual change is needed (potmeter) then any Schmitt-trigger inverting gate (HEF40106, 4093) a resistor, cap and 2 diodes can do the job, see: http://www.circuitstoday.com/pwm-motor-speed-control-circuit

Comment: For the record, an LDO is a type of linear regulator and therefore an adjective, not a noun in itself. You mean 'a regulator'.

Comment: A linear regulator costs around 8ct. A cheap microcontroller (smallest attiny) costs 25 ct in small quantities. Are you *sure* you'll be much cheaper including assembly cost if you do this in discrete components? (Hint: I doubt that.)

Comment: @Transistor - there is just the IC MCP8063 a few caps and resistors. not much to go by.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie - no manual adjustment needed.

Comment: @Marcus - Yeah, at the moment I think I may need to go with a microcontroller.

Answer (score 1):

This is do-able using some RC networks to make a ramp and a simple RC relaxation osc. from a CMOS Schmitt Trigger that goes 1/3 to 2/3 Vdd for 0 to 100%, so it’s a simple calculation to define the ramp levels, impedance and slew rate. But, as I am on the road, a complete solution is not handy.  Cost could be pennies in high volume.

Comment: This sounds like the answer I have been looking for. Does anyone have an example for me?

Comment: You ought to specify exactly, including frequency with tolerances as this is a pretty unique solution

Comment: Graham can you not define ANY Inputs? like supply and tolerance, start trigger, Retrigger tolerance time from power dropouts. Minimum duty cycle at start?

Comment: Tolerances are not critical and the only input will be the supply voltage (between 3V-12V. I have some parts coming in to day to do some testing. But if the ramp starts at anywhere between 0 - 30% duty it will be fine (not a precision system).

Comment: Another way is to use an Op Amp Relaxation Osc. with triangle input wave ( at desired PWM frequency) then use a power On Pull up slew rate to change duty cycle from 0 to 100% in 1 second.  The ouput can be inverted to give correct polarity if needed.